# Pointer vs. TType

Tags: delphi, class, pointers

I have what seems to be a pretty basic question, but I just wanted to make sure.

Is there a difference between those two?

```
var ClassArray: array of TMyClass;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  SetLength(ClassArray, Length(ClassArray)+1);
  ClassArray[Length(ClassArray)-1]:=Self;
end;

begin
  for i:=0 to x do
  ClassArray[i].MyProcedure;
```

and

```
var PointerArray: array of Pointer;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  SetLength(PointerArray, Length(PointerArray)+1);
  PointerArray[Length(PointerArray)-1]:=Self;
end;

begin
  for i:=0 to x do
  TMyClass(PointerArray[i]).MyProcedure;
```

Because from the way it's working when I play around with it, the only difference is that I cannot directly view the elements in PointerArray (as only the address is shown).

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question - You need to use `High()` instead of `Length()` inside of `TMyClass.Create()`.  You are trying to store your `Self` pointer to the wrong array index.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB yeah, I usually use `PointerArray[Length(PointerArray)-1]:=Self;`. By the way, is this different from the `High()` in terms of speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two versions are identical in terms of the code that the compiler generates. This is because an instance reference is implemented as a pointer.

The difference is that for the version based on pointers, the compiler does not know that the array contents are instance references. That's why you have to cast to `TMyClass` in order to be able to invoke a method, and why the debugger insight is only able to show you an address.

Comment: Yeah, I know why I can't see the contents of my class in the Pointer array. I just wanted to know whether they differ in terms of time or memory requirements, which you said they do not. Thanks